# Php 'update' command script possibly needs sql injection protection?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sql-injection, code-injection

My database recently suffered from a sql injection attack, mostly because I am relatively new to programming and did not know about something like that. I have been trying to learn how to prevent them, but I cannot figure out how for this script. I do have another type of script that I successfully implemented though. **How can I prevent an sql injection attack using this script?**

```
<?php

$autor = $_GET["multi"];
$autop = $_GET["multis"];

$sql = "UPDATE autoj SET autob = '$autop' WHERE autoq = '$autor'";

$hd = "something";
$dd =  $_GET['something'];
$ud = "something";
$pd = "something";

$mysqli = new mysqli($hd, $ud, $pd, $dd); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
}

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($result) {
....
```

Comment: Use a prepared statement or escape the data

Comment: Are you going to ask a separate question for the every script you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$hd = "something";
$dd = "PUT SOMETHING HERE";
$ud = "something";
$pd = "something";

$mysqli = new mysqli($hd, $ud, $pd, $dd); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
}

$autor = $_GET["multi"];
$autop = $_GET["multis"];
$autor = $mysqli->real_escape_string($autor);
$autop = $mysqli->real_escape_string($autop);

$sql = "UPDATE autoj SET autob = '$autop' WHERE autoq = '$autor'";
```

Also, on line two, I see you used $_GET['something'] to select a database. Don't.

Comment: $dd comes from a different script. That's all I need to be protected?

Comment: `$dd =  $_GET['something'];` was in the original code.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I prevent an sql injection attack using this script?

#### Exactly the same way as [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375987/protecting-mysql-database-from-injection-attacks-with-pdo-script)

Answer (score -1):

use mysqli_real_escape_string
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php